# Show that $g(A)$ is the transformation matrix of the endomorphism $(g(f))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vectorspace. Given an endomorphism $f:V \to V$. Let $A$ be the transformation matrix of $f$ with respect to a basis $v$ of $V$ and let $g(x)=g_0x^m+ \cdots g_{m-1}x+g_m$ be a polynomial.

Now I want to show that $g(A)$ is the transformation matrix of the endomorphism $g(f)$ with respect to the basis $v$ where $g(f)=g_0f^m+ \cdots + g_{m-1}f+g_m$id.

Maybe there is someone with a hint how to tackle this problem. I tried to work with a commutative diagram but that wasn't very useful. I'm worried that I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: Hint: can you prove it in the case where the degree of $g$ is $0$ or $1$? Can you extend it to the general case in some standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** For any endomorphism $h : V \to V$ and basis $v$, denote the matrix representation of $h$ w.r.t. $v$ by $[v]$; then, $[f] = A$.

By linearity it suffices to prove the claim for monic monomials, that is that
$$[f^m] = [f]^m ,$$ where $[h]$ denotes the matrix representation of $h$ w.r.t. $v$.

> But this follows from an inductive argument using the fact that, for any choice of basis, $$[pq] = [p][q]$$ for any endomorphisms $p, q$ on a vector space.